# updating state using name attribute on TextInput react-native

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-state-management

i'm attempting to update a state onChange within a form. When I type in the form my app crashes with this error

```
TypeError undefined is not an object react-native (evaluating e.target)
```

I'm trying to use [e.target.name] to select the appropriate state to update using my  elements.

maybe i'm missing something small but I have pretty much the exact same code running in a react web project and it works fine?

here's my current form

```
export default class CreateNote extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    title: "",
    who: "",
    time: ""
  };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  }

  onTextChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  createNoteView=()=>{
    if(this.state.modalVisible === true){
      return (
        <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>

              <Button title="cancel" onPress={()=>this.setState({modalVisible:false})}></Button>

                <TextInput
                  placeholder="title"
                  name = "title"
                  type="text"

                  onChange={()=>{this.onTextChange()}}
                />


                <TextInput
                  placeholder="who"
                  name = "who"
                  type="text"

                  onChange={()=>{this.onTextChange()}}
                />


                <TextInput
                  placeholder="when"
                  name = "time"
                  type="text"

                  onChange={()=>{this.onTextChange()}}
                />
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 22, width: 150 }}>
          <Button onPress={()=>{this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}} title="create"></Button>
      </View>
    )

  }


  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        {this.createNoteView()}
    </View>
    )

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onChangeText` method like below.

```
onTextChange = (name) => (value) => {
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
};

...other code...

<TextInput
  placeholder="title"
  onChangeText={this.onTextChange("title")}
/>
```

You can refer `onChangeText` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext)

If you want to use `onChange` instead of `onChangeText` then you should use somthing like `event.nativeEvent.text`

```
onTextChange = (name) => (event) => {
 this.setState({ [name]: event.nativeEvent.text });
};

...other code...

<TextInput
  placeholder="title"
  onChange={this.onTextChange("title")}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options for managing state:

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@mykhailogogol/use-react-form-state)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TextInput, View } from "react-native";


export default function () {
  const defaultState = {
    name: '',
    password: ''
  };
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state)
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput placeholder={'Name'} value={state.name} onChangeText={(name) => setState({...state, name})} />
      <TextInput placeholder={'Password'} value={state.password} onChangeText={(password) => setState({...state, password})} />
    </View>
  );
}
```